# Can't commit changes to github

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Whenever I try and to commit changes to my github repo I get this error.

> To git@github.com:antarr/3skeleton.git
>   ! [rejected]        master -> master
>   (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to
>   push some refs to
>   'git@github.com:antarr/3skeleton.git'
>   To prevent you from losing history,
>   non-fast-forward updates were rejected
>   Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git
>   pull') before pushing again.
>    See the
>   'Note about fast-forwards' section of
>   'git push --help' for details.

If I do `git pull` first, it changes some of the files on my machine. Which kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like files have been committed and pushed to the repository on github since you last updated.

doing a `git pull` will pull those changes down and merge them in with your changes. You can then test everything and make sure it still works, and then do a push.

It should not overwrite the changes that you have made and are trying to commit.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed the database.yml to not inlcude my password and when I pull it changes the password on my machine. Thank you.